# convert nvarchar of large length to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT acctcode 
FROM oact 
WHERE acctcode 
BETWEEN 42100000 AND 42100001;
```

when I run the above query I get an error :

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '100000000000000' overflowed an
>   int column.

acctcode is nvarchar type.
I have tried:

```
SELECT convert(bigint,Acctcode) as id 
FROM OACT 
WHERE acctcode 
BETWEEN 42100000 and 42100001;
```

It gives error :

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '100000000000000' overflowed an
>   int column.

Please help!!

Comment: Use `between '42100000' and '42100001'` instead, to avoid the conversion to int

Comment: Why do you use varchar to store bigint values?

Comment: Worse, @jarlh , it's an `nvarchar`. Because you (apparently) need 2 bytes per digit to store an 8 byte number. So a number like `-9223372036854775808` would be 40 bytes in size, rather than 8.

Comment: it is sap table ,it came preloaded with nvarchar type

Comment: @Larnu It's an account code - most account codes are alpha numeric in ERP systems, basically your customer account number for example. I do run into customers that insist that all values be completely numeric, which doesn't help their SOP/POP teams from searching for customers/suppliers - thank god there's usually a `name` column too!

Comment: If so, then my comments about `BETWEEN` in my answer are even more relevant that it should not used here, @Charleh . Numbers and Strings don't work the same. `5` is not `BETWEEN 49999 AND 50001` but `'5'` ***is*** `BETWEEN '49999' AND '50001'`.

Comment: @Larnu yes true, but from the perspective of an ERP system this is correct. Numer sequences/series usually work like this in that the prefix/suffix parts are constant and the length of the sequence is usually fixed. Add to that the fact that any screens the user will view the account list in will also show the data in alpha order (and will show 5 between 49999 and 50001) then it would be exactly what the user/developer expects.

Comment: *"and the length of the sequence is usually fixed"* Clearly that is not the case here though, @Charleh . `N'100000000000000'` is much longer in length than `42100000`. If they were fixed width, I agree, it would not be such a problem. For example instead of `N'42100000'` the value was `N'000000042100000'`. Then the OP could simple use `BETWEEN N'000000042100000' AND N'000000042100001'` and it would work exactly as everyone expects.

Comment: Just because the sequence length isn't necessarily fixed, it doesn't mean it's not still correct - https://imgur.com/a/B68TTya - though I agree it's something the OP needs to be aware of when querying if they aren't familiar with how the system lists data.

Comment: @Larnu it could well be that the number is indeed `42100000` and not `000000042100000`, but you are probably right here. I guess these are all questions for the OP though! Mixed lengths are sometimes used but mostly avoided because of the alpha sorting making lists look as per the screenshot in my previous comment. I never rule anything out with ERP data though as it's 99.9% human input, and humans are inherently wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the implicit conversion of the VARCHAR column in the WHERE clause.

The string '100000000000000' is to big for a normal INT.

So look for the strings.

```
select convert(bigint,Acctcode) as id 
from OACT 
where acctcode between '42100000' and '42100001'
  and len(acctcode) = 8;
```

This will look for acctcode's that are alphabetically in that range.
But it'll work fine for numbers.
*(assuming that the acctcode's don't have leading spaces)*

Another way is to use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql), if your Sql Server version supports it.

```
select Acctcode as id 
from OACT 
where TRY_CONVERT(INT, acctcode) between 42100000 and 42100001;
```

A `TRY_CONVERT` returns NULL when the conversion fails, instead of error.
So this wouldn't even raise errors on acctcode's that contain letters.

But such function is often non-[Sargable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217983/153574).
So this method could be slower if acctcode is indexed, and the query would ignore that index.

Comment: The first one will work "fine" for the 2 values, that they have, however, for others it is unlikely to work as the OP expects. For example `'500'` **is** between `'4999999999'` and `'5000000001'`. Ideally the OP needs to fix their data types. `(n)varchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type.

Comment: For the latter, for a large table, this is going to be awful for performance, as it'll force a scan of the entire table. Also, considering the OP has values like `N'100000000000000'` then `bigint` would be a "better" choice if this solution were used. But there's no real "win" with either here, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes with code fields that get data from different sources then one can expect different formats. And using a number type field isn't an option then.  It just becomes one of those things that one has to accept & deal with somehow. But I added a length check, to deal with the short string between larger strings.

Comment: @Larnu most likely the account numbers are based on a sequence/number series. The 4XX part will likely be the prefix (maybe segregated by account type) with the right hand numeric part incrementing off the back of this.

Answer (score 0):

In your second query convert to bigint would happen only after the values are selected, but before that they are implicitly converted to int by where clause giving you the error. Try this instead:

```
select Acctcode from OACT where cast(acctcode as bigint) between 42100000 and 42100001;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data choice, and that you have a very small range of values (`BETWEEN 42100000 AND 42100001`) you would be better off simply using an `IN`, and passing the correct data type, so that it's SARGable:

```
SELECT acctcode 
FROM oact 
WHERE acctcode IN (N'42100000',N'42100001');
```

If you are parametrising this, I suggest using a user-defined table type, and using that.

I strongly recommend against using `BETWEEN` with `nvarchar` values here, as if you had something like `WHERE acctcode BETWEEN N'499997' AND N'500001'` then a value like `N'5'` would be returned.

Using something like `CONVERT` (or `TRY_CONVERT`) wrapped around the column (`acctcode`) would cause SARGability problems, as a full scan would be required. Considering you have values like `N'100000000000000'`, this suggests a large number of rows, which would be some awful performance.